# compare two string having one is separated by space using criteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I want to check equality of two strings and it should return data if one string separated by space.

ex: String 1 = softskill (from table)

String 2 = soft skill (from input)

using below code

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TableClass.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("fieldName", "string1"));
```

Is there any way?

Comment: what do you mean by it should return data if one string separated by space. which data sould be returned ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Restrictions.like()`. The example below should work for your case, but it will also match "soft someOtherText skill".

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TableClass.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.like("fieldName", "soft%skill"));
```

You could try parsing the input and doing something like this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TableClass.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.eq("fieldName", "soft skill")),
    Restrictions.eq("fieldName", "softskill"));
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp